# my code shows error during execution while the structure is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm writing a program that write some website inside hosts file
but when i'm trying run the program it's show me an error that the directory is not found

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

host_temp = "hosts"
host_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_list = ["www.facebook.com","www.instagram.com", "www.youtube.com"]

while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,20) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,23,1):
        print("Working hours!!!")
        with open(host_temp, "r+") as file:
            content = file.read()
        for website in website_list:
            if website in content:
                pass
            else:
                file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
    else:
        print("Fun hours!!!")
    time.sleep(5)
```

and this is the output

```
Working hours!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALAA\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.38.2\hello\web site blocker\web_site_blocker.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open(host_temp, "r+") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hosts'
```

Comment: What is `hosts` ? Is it a folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with the structure of your program. It is just saying that it cannot find the file you say exists. You need to check the filetype of your file (you can usually see it next to your file name or in the file's properties). The majority of files have an extension.

If your file is a text file (.txt), for example, your filename would be:

```
host_temp = "hosts.txt"
```

Comment: i tried same issue

Comment: @AlaaKM what is your file's full name? did you check it?

Comment: C:\Users\ALAA\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.38.2\hello\web site blocker this is the path file

Comment: and the file name is hosts and the type is txt

Comment: @AlaaKM This should work then..

Comment: but it did not!!

Comment: I can't help you more without seeing your folders and such.

Comment: whatsapp me +971504741796

Answer (score 0):

seems like your code should be like below with full path.  if you don't provide full path then python will search for 'hosts' file where your py file is stored.

```
with open(host_path, "r+") as file:
```

Comment: i tried same issue